# Convert Multidimensional array to single array in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

It's probably beginner question but I'm going through documentation for 
longer time already and I can't find any solution and i have an array which 
is multidimensional given below format.

```
/* This is how my array is currently */
Array
(
  [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => a
                [title_num] =>1 
                [status] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => Mr
                [title_num] => 82
                [status] => 1
            )
     )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => b
                [title_num] =>25 
                [status] => 2
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => c
                [title_num] =>45
                [status] => 2
            )
     )
)
```

I want to convert this array into this form

```
 /*Now, I want to simply it down to this*/
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => a
                [title_num] =>1 
                [status] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => Mr
                [title_num] => 82
                [status] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => b
                [title_num] =>25 
                [status] => 2
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [title] => c
                [title_num] =>45
                [status] => 2
            )
     )
```

I have tried array_flatten,array_map PHP built in function
    A link or anything to point me in the right direction will be highly 
    appreciated

Comment: @Gareth Jones ,i checked this not working

Comment: @GarethJones It is not working as per OP way.

Comment: @NaveenN Thank you for checking

Answer (score 2):

here you go

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $arr)
{
    $result = array_merge($result , $arr);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: this is straightforward!

Comment: @Akintunde007 Thank you , its working.. is there any built in function to do same without foreach

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $n1) {
        foreach ($n1 as $n2) {
            $newArr[$i]['title']=$n2['title'];
            $newArr[$i]['title_num']=$n2['title_num'];
            $newArr[$i]['status']=$n2['status'];
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Or simpler as suggested in the comments

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
    foreach ($array[$i] as $n2) {
        $newArr[$i]['title']=$n2['title'];
        $newArr[$i]['title_num']=$n2['title_num'];
        $newArr[$i]['status']=$n2['status'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second `foreach` use `$n1` instead of `$array`? Also, why not `for`? Using `for` the counter is explicitly created in the parameters.

Comment: Corrected, you were right, thanks <3

Comment: De nada, you're welcome. I actually prefer your answer as opposed to the others, but I still think `for` is better haha.

Comment: In this case I think the same thing, but I'd decided to go for my classic haha, is beautiful how we can do the same thing in so many ways.

Comment: @Zeke added the way you suggested

Comment: Well, I would have used 2 `for` loops, and I would have saved `count($array)` and `count($n1)` in a variable to avoid too many function calls... but I guess that works too. I mean, I think about legibility, efficiency, practicality, etc.. so those small details make a huge impact in greater proportions.

Comment: haha it will work, but yes, I did it backwards

Comment: Check the edits, I'm not exactly happy about being mentioned in the answer. Especially when I wouldn't have written that block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another trick to solve your problem,

```
function custom_filter($array) { 
    $temp = [];
  array_walk($array, function($item,$key) use (&$temp){
      foreach($item as $value)
         $temp[] = $value;
  });
  return $temp;
}
```

**array_walk** — *Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array*

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92ff39fbc414420a13a523ce3041b7aef2a78d0f).